# How to Pass Form Data in Post Request using ionic-native-http in capacitor?

Tags: ionic-framework, multipartform-data

I have used a Validation Form to take the input from users and I have a submit button on which submit() function is being called.

insertuserdata() is a function in service.ts file where api is being called. I am passing form data in the api. File(e.g pdf,doc,docx etc.) can also be passed to the api as multi part form data.

But I am using Ionic-Native-Http to pass multi part form data using capacitor.

I am getting the error as status 415.Please help with this.

```
submit()
  {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (!this.ionicForm.valid) {
      console.log('Please provide all the required values!')
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log(this.ionicForm.value)
    }

    console.log("this is deptid", this.deptid)
    console.log("this is description", this.ionicForm.controls["description"].value)
    console.log("this is cid", this.ionicForm.controls["subquery"].value)
    console.log("this is location", this.ionicForm.controls["location"].value)
    console.log("query",this.ionicForm.controls["query"].value)


    console.log("Insert Form Data")
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('postedby', this.employeeId);
    formData.append('description', this.ionicForm.controls["description"].value);
    formData.append('location', this.ionicForm.controls["location"].value);
    formData.append('deptid', this.deptid);
    formData.append('cid', this.ionicForm.controls["subquery"].value);
     formData.append('file', this.ionicForm.get('profile').value);


     console.log("Insert Api call")

     this.c2s.insertuserdata(formData).then((insertdata: any) =>{
      console.log("Insert Response",insertdata)
   })
```

```
insertuserdata(formData) {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'enctype': 'multipart/form-data;', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
  };

    this.insert = this.http1.post("https://webapplnapp.tatapower.com/tpc_restfull_service/api/connecttosolve/postQuery", formData, httpOptions);
   
    return this.insert
  }
```

Comment: Did you managed to fix this?

Comment: `Capacitor HTTP` doesn't work with `FormData`. Pass your data like a js object and keep `application/json` content-type

Comment: did you fix this I have the same problem with form data and capacitor http